# How to create a border that looks like a tag?

Tags: tag

When I say a tag, I say a tag similar to the one used in the **[Stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)** network.

Exemple:

[image]

How can I create a `tag` with rounded edges that allow colors in Hexadecimal form?

Are there any special packages that already have this type of drawing?

Comment: One word: `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More or less:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newtcbox{mytag}{size=small, sharp corners, fontupper=\sffamily, colback=blue!20, colframe=blue!20, colupper=blue, nobeforeafter}

\begin{document}
\mytag{ux} \mytag{segurança} \mytag{senhas}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

I've included colors defined with HTML model (hexadecimal), rounded corners (although original example showed them sharp) and `before upper` option to force similar height and depth for all tags.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\definecolor{myback}{HTML}{ADA8F6}
\definecolor{mytext}{HTML}{858585}

\newtcbox{mytag}{%
    size=small, 
    fontupper=\sffamily, 
    colback=myback, 
    colframe=myback, 
    colupper=mytext, 
    nobeforeafter, 
    before upper=\vphantom{Ähgy}}

\begin{document}
\mytag{ux} \mytag{segurança} \mytag{senhas}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should make them take up the same height (strut or phantoms).

Comment: How do I make it round?

Comment: @cura Why don't you play with it a bit? Maybe try seeing what deleting `sharp corners` does?

Comment: How to put in hexadecimal? @Ignasi

Comment: Question Edited.

Answer (score 6):

Also with TikZ alone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{mybluea}{HTML}{87CEEB}
\definecolor{myblueb}{HTML}{0000FF}

\newcommand{\mytag}[1]{\tikz{\node[rounded corners, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex, fill=mybluea, draw=myblueb, text=myblueb] {#1};}}

\begin{document}
\mytag{ux} \mytag{segurança} \mytag{senhas}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put the colors in hexadecimal?

Comment: @cura Of course you can, see my renewed answer!

Comment: Very good, I got this way. I already left my +1